# How can I do math directly in LaTeX?

Tags: fontsize

How can I do math directly in LaTeX?
I don't want to calculate it first and input the value to it.

```
font=\fontsize{10/0.88348}{12}\selectfont
```

Comment: In what context would you use that?

Comment: @egreg I'm using it for my TikZ drawing. `\draw (A) node[above, font=\fontsize{10/0.88348}{12}\selectfont] {$V_X$}`. I want to do  this to account for scale factor in the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\fpeval`

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % or define a scalable font in the preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (1,0) {};
\draw (A) node[above, font=\fontsize{\fpeval{10/0.88348}}{0}\selectfont] {$V_X$};
\draw (B) node[above, font=\fontsize{\fpeval{10*1.35}}{0}\selectfont] {$V_X$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]